# Counting duplicate strings in array with equals()

Tags: java, arrays, string, nested-loops

Brand new to Java and I cannot seem to figure this out:

All I'm trying to do is print a duplicate string and the number of times it shows up in an array (not using hash tables or anything like that, just very simplistically).

Let's say for an array like this:

```
tempArray = {"dogs", "cats", "dogs", "dogs", "mice", "snakes", "cats"}
```

Here's my code thus far:

```
int flowerCount = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < tempArray.length - 1; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < tempArray.length; k++) {
              if( (tempArray[j].equals(tempArray[k])) && (j != k) ) {
                    System.out.println(tempArray[j]);
                    flowerCount++;
               }

         }

 }
```

Obviously this doesn't work, what am I doing wrong here? This seems like it should be so simple to do, but I can't get the nested loops and counter right.

Comment: Why does it obviously not work? What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: As i stated, the expected output is "print a duplicate string and the number of times it shows up in an array ". All that it does currently is print the duplicated item an erroneous number of times

Comment: are you looking for a specific string that is known before the function runs, or are you trying to find all strings that are duplicated?  so, in your example, should your output be "dogs"*3, "cats"*2?

Comment: You have a one-dimensional array. Having the inner for loop is over-complicating things.

Comment: Please provide the expected output based on your test sample.

Comment: Are you familiar with Java `Map`?

Comment: @DrewKennedy How should I simplify this?

Comment: @rothloup Trying to find all strings that are duplicated and how many times those strings occur in the array

Comment: @Malvin9000 I think if you just change the second for to this `for (int k = 0 ; k <= tempArray.length; k++)` it would work.

Comment: @Malvin9000 Is your name Malvin, or you live in Montevideo?

Comment: I'd just sort the array and look for equal consecutive elements.

Comment: @AndyTurner That's another good option.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you for that, I will try to sort — what's the best way to count the consecutive elements? Should I do that in the inner for loop?

Comment: Check the value of the current index, `j`, against the previous index, `j - 1`. Just make sure the first check doesn't happen on 0 as index -1 quite likely doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array using `Arrays.sort`. This will put equal elements next to each other. Then you can simply iterate through the list with a while loop, looking for consecutive elements which are equal.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < arr.length) {
  int start = i;
  while (i < arr.length && arr[i].equals(arr[start])) {
    ++i;
  }
  int count = i - start;
  System.out.println(arr[start] + " " + count);
}
```

Comment: You can do it with one loop only and print previous when element changes.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to count duplicates is to try to add them to a set.  A set doesn't allow duplicates, so each time adding a string fails, it is because the string already exists in the set.

The `add()` method in a set returns a boolean, indicating if the add was successful or not.  If the string you are trying to add is already in the set, the add will fail and the method will return false.

So something like:

```
HashSet<String> yourSet = new HashSet<>(); //Could be any kind of set, I'm just used to HashSets
int j = 0; j < tempArray.length - 1; j++) {
    if (yourSet.add(tempArray[j]) {
        //String was added succesfully, so it is not a duplicate.
    }  else {
        //String is duplicate.  Increment a duplicate counter for this string (and start at 2, if you want to include the initial occurence that is already in the set
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with array and for

```
String printed = "";
    for(String auxOne : tempArray){
        int CountRepeat = 0;
        for(String auxTwo : tempArray){
            if(auxOne.equals(auxTwo)){
                CountRepeat++;
            }
        }
        if(CountRepeat>1 && (printed.indexOf(auxOne)==-1)){
            printed += auxOne;
            System.out.println(auxOne + " : " + CountRepeat);
        }
    }

}
```